# Combining multiple measurements: how to calculate the uncertainty in this case?

Tags: experimental-physics, probability, error-analysis, statistics

Let's say I have an experiment where I measure some variable $D$ (in the experiment I am grading it is the diffusion constant but I want to keep the discussion general). There are two runs of measurements with 3 measurements per run. Each run should reproduce the same value of $D$. Let us assume the 'real' value of $D$ is 10. The following hypothetical data was generated:

\begin{array}[ccc|c]
     \  & \text{measurement 1} & \text{measurement 2} & \text{measurement 3} & \textbf{average}\\
\text{run 1} & 9.9\pm 0.1  & 10.0\pm 0.1 & 10.1\pm 0.1 & 10.0\pm \sigma_1 \\
\text{run 2} & 6.0\pm 0.1  & 8.0\pm 0.1  & 10.0\pm 0.1 & 8.0\pm \sigma_2
\end{array}
The second run was worse (there were less particles to calculate $D$ from), but due to the way the uncertainties were calculated, the datapoints have similar uncertainty to the first run. Now how should we calculate the average uncertainty of each run? Naively we would calculate the uncertainty by propagation of error using a [weighted mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean), which would give $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=0.1/\sqrt{3-1}=0.1/\sqrt{2}$. Notably, this would give the same error for both run 1 and 2.

We could also calculate simply calculate the standard deviation of the two runs. This would give $\sigma_1=0.1$ and $\sigma_2=2$. This would be better in the sense that it captures the high variability of the second run. If we would then calculate a weighted mean of the two runs it would more heavily weight the second run which would improve the result. A downside is that now the error tends to capture more systematic error instead of intrinsic experimental uncertainty.

So my question is how would I correctly calculate the errors on the averages in this case?

Comment: *The second run was worse (there were less particles to calculate D from), but due to the way the uncertainties were calculated, the datapoints have similar uncertainty to the first run.* This is a contradictory statement in that either *there were less particles to calculate D from* affects the uncertainty and should be included as a source of potential error  or it does not. Without clearer indication of how the data and the errors were obtained it really is not possible to give a reasoned answer except perhaps to say that if you believe in the quoted errors then go for the weighted mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systematic error is uncertainty. The two measurement runs do not have the same uncertainty, regardless of how your stated error bar is calculated. If the error bar calculated from statistics alone (e.g. standard deviation) does not capture the full uncertainty, then you need to estimate the systematic error and include that in your expanded uncertainty calculation.

Comment: I think this answers my question. How would you then calculate the uncertainty in this case?

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion systematic (“Type B”) uncertainty can be really challenging. You just have to use your physical intuition and list every way you can think of for your measurement to be off. You could start with the stated calibration errors of your instruments and then also include environmental, alignment, etc. errors. For each variable, calculate how sensitive your final measurement is (“sensitivity coefficients”), then add all the uncertainties together in quadrature, including the statistics-calculated uncertainty (“Type A”).

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion in the metrology community, an error analysis of this sort can be an entire paper.